# Remove mysql service from WAMPServer

Tags: mysql, mariadb, wampserver

I have installed **WAMPServer 3.1.7** in my server and working fine. But due to environment restriction I have to remove the database from it. I have both **mysql** and **mariadb** installed in server.

How can I remove these databases from WAMPServer?

Comment: log in to phpmyadmin and delete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to @RiggsFolly 's answer(After unchecking db names from the menu), I did some more action to remove the **db** files from the server itself as follows(screenshot attached):

```
WAMP icon(Right click) -> Tools ->Delete Unused versions -> 
{Delete unwanted versions of DB, PHP, apche}
```

[image]

Deleting the folder directly from the **WAMP** folder will cause crash as **WAMP** server still expecting those folders and versions to be available. Doing this way ensures **WAMP** Server will not check for older versions and it will run without any crashes.

Answer (score 18):

You can deactivate both `MySQL` and/or `mariaDB` in WAMPServer if you want to. You simply use the wampmanager icon in the system tray.

Start WAMPServer, then

```
RIGHT CLICK the wampmanager -> Wamp Settings
```

You should see something like the below image.

*NOTE* In the image I have already deactivated `mariaDB`

Where you see `Allow MySQL` and `Allow mariaDB` they will be ticked with a green tick.

Click one of these and that database will be removed. Allow a few seconds for WAMPServer to complete the task and restart itself, then click the other database and allow that to complete and restart WAMPServer.

When you go back to this menu the green ticks should have been removed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For removing files, I did some more actions, i will add it as answer so that others can user it

Comment: Clicking this appears to restart wamp, but after it is done restarting, the green checkmark is still there.

Comment: @kloddant What version of WAMPServer and Wampmanager are you running

Comment: @RiggsFolly Wampserver Version 3.2.3 - 64bit.  Is Wampmanager separate?  Do you know how I would find that version?  This has been a perpetual problem on this computer for years.  I probably just need to eventually reinstall wamp.

Comment: Double click on WAPManager W icon in the system tray, a windows will open introducing you to wampmanager

Comment: WAMPServers current version is 3.2.8, upgrade that from the [WAMPServer backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) Its so much easier to navigate than Sourceforge

Comment: Read the [WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2) Specifically the thread at the top titled `WAMPServer 3 All you need to know`